# Update-alternatives Module Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to update 'alternatives' module for Ansible.

The default module can be found here : https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/blob/devel/system/alternatives.py

I'm trying to add the `remove` arg for `update-alternatives` command.

My updated code is the following :

```
DEFAULT_LINK_PRIORITY = 50

def main():

module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec = dict(
        name = dict(required=True),
        path  = dict(required=True),
        link = dict(required=False),
        ### Mode Added by isador999 ###
        mode = dict(required=False),
    )
)

params = module.params
name = params['name']
path = params['path']
link = params['link']
### Mode Added by isador999 ###
mode = params['mode']

UPDATE_ALTERNATIVES =  module.get_bin_path('update-alternatives',True)

current_path = None
all_alternatives = []

(rc, query_output, query_error) = module.run_command(
    [UPDATE_ALTERNATIVES, '--query', name]
)

if rc == 0:
    for line in query_output.splitlines():
        split_line = line.split(':')
        if len(split_line) == 2:
            key = split_line[0]
            value = split_line[1].strip()
            if key == 'Value':
                current_path = value
            elif key == 'Alternative':
                all_alternatives.append(value)
            elif key == 'Link' and not link:
                link = value

    if not mode or mode == "install":
        if current_path != path:
            try:
                # install the requested path if necessary
                if path not in all_alternatives:
                    module.run_command(
                        [UPDATE_ALTERNATIVES, '--install', link, name, path, str(DEFAULT_LINK_PRIORITY)],
                        check_rc=True
                    )

                # select the requested path
                module.run_command(
                    [UPDATE_ALTERNATIVES, '--set', name, path],
                    check_rc=True
                )

                module.exit_json(changed=True)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError, cpe:
                module.fail_json(msg=str(dir(cpe)))
        else:
            module.exit_json(changed=False)
    elif mode == "remove":
        if current_path == path:
            module.run_command(
                [UPDATE_ALTERNATIVES, '--remove', name, path],
                check_rc=True
from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
main()
```

When I use this new module, with `install` or `remove` mode, Ansible returns to me :

`failed: [HOST] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
invalid output was:
 * keychain 2.7.1 ~ http://www.funtoo.org
 * Found existing ssh-agent: 2352
 * Known ssh key: /path/id_rsa
FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting`

With `remove` mode, the script seems to be working, my Java links are correctly deleted, but I don't understand what Ansible is searching to have no error ...

Have you any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

If your code above is copy-pasted as-is, then one problem is that you are importing from `ansible.module_utils.basic` **after** the `main()` function.

`main()` needs the definition of `AnsibleModule` to be available when parsed. You can see the imports happening at the very top of the original file, in comparison.

HTH

Comment: I would recommend enrighing the parameter's dictionary with:
 elements='str', choices=['install', 'remove'])

Comment: Sorry, I meant:
I would recommend enriching the parameter's dictionary with: choices=['install', 'remove'])

And I would also strongly recommend you submitting a patch to this module in the community.general repository.